# Select a distinct sum from a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I'm really racking my brain trying to figure this one out.

Given the following sample data:

```
CustomerNo      Product      Country      Month      Price     CostA    CostB
CUSTA           PRD          AU           1          100       200      300
CUSTB           PRD          AU           1          115       200      300
CUSTA           PRD          AU           2          120       250      350
CUSTB           PRD          AU           2          150       250      350
CUSTC           PRD          AU           3          125       300      400
CUSTD           PRD          AU           3          135       300      400
```

Prices are stored by customer and costs (CostA and CostB) are stored by country.

I need to get the "distinct" sum of costs based on a range.

For example I need to get the sum  of the costs for 1st quarter which is Jan - Feb.

The correct sum would be 200+250+300 for CostA and 300+350+400 for CostB

The following query returns the sum of all costs for a country for example 200+250+300 * 2 for CostA.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
c.Country,
costAQ1.SumGross AS costAQ1
FROM Customers c 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Country,
SUM(CostA) AS SumGross
FROM Customers
WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
GROUP BY
Country
) AS costAQ1
ON p.Country = costAQ1.Country
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

EDIT:

This code seems to have done it

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        c.Country,
        CostA.SumGross as CostA,
        CostB.SumGross as CostB
FROM    Customers c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  Country
        SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS SumGross
    FROM    Customers
    WHERE   [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    GROUP BY 
        Country
) AS CostA
ON c.Country = CostA.Country
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  Country, 
        SUM(DISTINCT CostB) AS SumGross
    FROM    Customers
    WHERE   [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    GROUP BY 
        Country
) AS CostB
ON c.Country = CostB.Country
```

Returns:

```
Country     CostA    CostB
AU          750      1050
```

Comment: The external `JOIN` is redundant.Your expected output isn't clear. If you wish to group by conutry, your current result is fine.

Comment: I can't see what would be wrong with that. The sum is 1500 for AU. isn't it? what am i missing?

Comment: @FilipeSilva - no, the sum for AU CostA needs to be 750, the `DISTINCT` value in CostA by country.

Comment: You want to sum only distinct values? this doesn't make sense..

Comment: @Yosi Costs are by country while price is stored by customer.  Price and cost values are used to calculate a net price: Price - CostA - CostB = NPR.  So to do a weighted average, we take the sum of the price divided by the DISTINCT sum of the costs.

Comment: This `JOIN` is TOTALLY redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would do that, maybe you got duplicate values in there somewhere and you are trying to ignore them. Try this:

```
SELECT Country, SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS SumGross
FROM Customers
WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
GROUP BY Country
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6472f/5)</kbd>

Edit:

You could achieve that last query you posted just with:

```
SELECT Country,
  SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS SumGrossA,
  SUM(DISTINCT CostB) AS SumGrossB
FROM Customers
WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY Country
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6472f/7)</kbd>

EDIT:

To include extra Quarters, You would do:

```
SELECT a.Country,
  a.SumGrossAQ1,
  a.SumGrossBQ1,
  b.SumGrossAQ2,
  b.SumGrossBQ2
FROM (
  SELECT Country,
    SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS SumGrossAQ1,
    SUM(DISTINCT CostB) AS SumGrossBQ1
  FROM Customers
  WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3
  GROUP BY Country
  ) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Country,
    SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS SumGrossAQ2,
    SUM(DISTINCT CostB) AS SumGrossBQ2
  FROM Customers
  WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 4 AND 6
  GROUP BY Country
  ) b ON a.country = b.country
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6472f/10)</kbd>
In this example you don't have data for Q2, But try it in your data.

Comment: The costs by country are stored in a different table than the costs by customer.  Using a temp table, I put them together so I can calculate the net price.  Works fine by customer but when I want to see the weighted average by country, I need only the distinct costs by country and month summed up.

Comment: This will not give his expected output.. you will first need to sum by country and month..

Comment: @Tom. If you want to sum by month, you would GROUP BY month also.

Comment: Simply adding GROUP BY month will also won't work, you will need to wrap it with another aggregation..

Comment: Actually this is working, I will edit my OP with the SQL that I am using that works.

Comment: @Tom. I wasn't seeing the big picture, but yes, using this query for each column would give you what you want. You could probably only do one query and do both SUMS in it GROUPED BY country.

Comment: @Tom. I added a new query that does the same as your last working query, in a simpler way.

Comment: @FilipeSilva, works great.  I can get CostAQ1 and CostBQ1 (Month 1 to 3) fairly simply.  Now if I wanted to get Q2 (Month 4 to 6) inline i.e., Country, costAQ1, costAQ2, costBQ1, costBQ2 is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: For that you should use the approach you were using of wrapping the query with another select, inner join with country. And you would do the same as this query, but for the Q2. Was this clear? Or not so much? :p

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p.Country, (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT CostA) FROM Customers WHERE Country = p.Country and month between 1 and 3 ) AS costAQ1,
(SELECT SUM(DISTINCT CostA) FROM Customers WHERE Country = p.Country and month between 4 and 6 ) AS costAQ2, etc. FROM Customers p` something like that?

Comment: That could work, but it wasn't what i was saying. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Country, SUM(month_cost) AS SumGross
FROM (SELECT Country,Month, SUM(DISTINCT CostA) AS month_cost
      FROM Customers
      WHERE [Month] BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
      GROUP BY Country,Month) A
GROUP BY Country
```